# Recover Tabular Model project/model

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, ssms, tabular

I have made a tabular model which is currently deployed on a SSAS server.
I made my project in my C Drive and my Drive is now dead.

Can I somehow download my model that is deployed on the  Analysis Services Server?
Or its basically lost?

I tried connecting to it but it tells me that its only possible for multi-dimensional.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new project in SSDT and then import the deployed tabular model.  When creating a new project, select the "Import from Server (Tabular)" option, connect to the SSAS instance where it's deployed, and choose the your tabular model.  One thing to keep in mind is that this option does not reset any metadata, deployment targets, or connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice, if not using a Git repository or any other soruce control platform, **is to save the XMLA script of the cube, from the server, periodically**.

Go to the Tabular Model Server and you right click and script as, and save all the necessary objects.